# Does anybody know I can load twitter data into android with lists in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, twitter

What I need to do is to display a twitter feed but also be able to update my twitter using a text box and submit button. Please help

Comment: You need to provide more details on what you have already tried.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i have created the first half of just adding the text box and button but what i need to do now is add a text box and button so you can enter any twitter feed you like. When the button is clicked, switch to a second activity that uses a ListView and ArrayAdapter to display all the contents of the twitter feed. I still have to create the second activity but im not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code from here - http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/android-programming-tutorial-a-simple-twitter-feed-reader/

Download the full java code and manifests at the bottom  of the page.

```
public ArrayList<Tweet> getTweets(String searchTerm, int page) {
  String searchUrl = 
        "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@" 
        + searchTerm + "&rpp=100&page=" + page;

  ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = 
        new ArrayList<Tweet>();

  HttpClient client = new  DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

  ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = 
        new BasicResponseHandler();

  String responseBody = null;
  try {
    responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  JSONObject jsonObject = null;
  JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

  try {
    Object obj = parser.parse(responseBody);
    jsonObject=(JSONObject)obj;
  }catch(Exception ex){
    Log.v("TEST","Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
  }

  JSONArray arr = null;

  try {
    Object j = jsonObject.get("results");
    arr = (JSONArray)j;
  } catch(Exception ex){
    Log.v("TEST","Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
  }

  for(Object t : arr) {
    Tweet tweet = new Tweet(
      ((JSONObject)t).get("from_user").toString(),
      ((JSONObject)t).get("text").toString(),
      ((JSONObject)t).get("profile_image_url").toString()
    );
    tweets.add(tweet);
  }

  return tweets;
}
```